# Geometry Nodes - Unique Frame Offset for Each Instance?

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers, shader-nodes, image-sequence

I am currently working on an animation that resembles a split-flap display like the ones you'd see in an airport. To accomplish this, I am using Geometry Nodes to instance several modules on a plane. The instanced module has an image sequence applied to it to depict the flapping action.

To make the animation more dynamic, I want each instance to show a different frame of the image sequence. In other words, I am looking to change the frame offset of the image sequence for each instance individually.

[image]

Is there a method to achieve this? Can the frame offset be manipulated within the Geometry Nodes structure?

I thought about using drivers to control the offset value, but I must admit, my experience with drivers is quite limited. If using drivers is the correct approach, could you guide me on how to set this up?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Save your animation in an image atlas, meaning that all frames should be in a single image file. Then you can manipulate the UV coordinates to dynamically access any frame data within that image.
Alternatively use some script to automatize adding a lot of nodes to load all those frames at once and a tree of switches that base which image is sampled based on frame index provided.